# Export each minute of MP3 into separate WAV

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-fingerprinting

This is definitely a strange question but I'm looking for a way to split an mp3 mix of 60 minutes into 60 separate 1 minute long wav files to use with an audio fingerprinting API like Echonest.

Is this possible in a single ffmpeg command or would I have to run multiple iterations of ffmpeg with a the following values:

-ss is the startpoint in seconds.
-t is the duration in seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the segment muxer in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 60 output%03d.mp3
```

For a 4 minute input this results in:

```
$ ls -m1 output*.mp3
output000.mp3
output001.mp3
output002.mp3
output003.mp3
```

Since `-codec copy` enables [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode re-encoding will be avoided. See the [segment](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) documentation for more information and examples.